# defining the Hessian as zero

Tags: python, python-3.x, hessian-matrix, scipy-optimize

While using scipy.optimize.minimize with the trust-constr method I got this UserWarning:

```
 scipy\optimize\_hessian_update_strategy.py:187: UserWarning: delta_grad == 0.0. Check if the approximated function is linear. If the function is linear better results can be obtained by defining the Hessian as zero instead of using quasi-Newton approximations. 'approximations.', UserWarning)
```

I have a linear function so I want to try to set the hessian as zero. But how does this work? I tried the easiest way with "hess = None" as parameter. Okay, a bad try.

This is the line calling the solver:

```
solution = scopt.minimize(minimizeFunction,initialGuess ,method='trust-constr', constraints=cons,options={'disp':True,'verbose':3},bounds=bnds)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define the constraint, you want to set

```py
    hess = lambda x: numpy.zeros((n, n))
```

Here `n` is the dimension of the array. Notice that you can also use a  [LinearConstraint object](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint.html#scipy.optimize.LinearConstraint)

Comment: thanks for the answer. I got It without setting the hessian matrix.

Comment: what's the role of the v in the lambda definition?

Comment: Yuca: that v was extra args that were relevant only in my problem. I've eliminated it for clarity.

Comment: @TupacAmaru thank you. However when I add `hess` parameter in `optimize.minimize`, I get the following error: `TypeError: <lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 4 were given`