# UserWarning when using scipy.optimize.minimize with method 'trust-constr'

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize, hessian-matrix

I am trying to minimize a function using `scipy.optimize.minimize` and I get the following errors:

```
Singular Jacobian matrix. Using SVD decomposition to perform the factorizations.

delta_grad == 0.0. Check if the approximated function is linear. If the function is linear better results can be obtained by defining the Hessian as zero instead of using quasi-Newton approximations.
```

My objective function is simply something around those lines:

```
def obj_func(x, x_new, idx, multipliers):
    x_tot = pd.concat([pd.Series(x, index=trade_syms), x_unchanged])
    obj = abs(x_tot.dot(multipliers))
    return obj
```

I checked [the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56310261/defining-the-hessian-as-zero) and I added the `hess` parameter in my `optimize.minimize` function so that it now looks like this:

```
optimize.minimize(obj_func,
                  x0=x0,
                  args=(a1, a2, a3),
                  bounds=((-0.5, 0.5),) * Nc,
                  constraints=cons,
                  hess=lambda x1,x2,x3,x4: np.zeros((Nc, Nc)),
                  method='trust-constr')
```

But I still get the same error.
My constraints are just 2 equality constraints:

```
cons = [{'type': 'eq', 'fun': func1},
        {'type': 'eq', 'fun': func2}]
```

Also, I dont know why I need to add `x1`,`x2`,`x3`,`x4` to the lambda function. I did it because `hess = lambda x: numpy.zeros((n, n))` gave me an error like `Expected 4 arguments to unpack, but got only one`.

Anything I am missing here?

Comment: Please provide a minimal complete **reproducible** example. Otherwise, it's hard to help appropriately. That being said, note that the abs function is not differentiable and so is your objective function. To answer one of your questions: Your objective function depends on three additional arguments, so the same holds for the objective gradient and the objective hessian. However, `lambda x, *args: np.zeros((Nc, Nc))` should work, too.

Comment: Thank you @joni, that helps understanding why the hessian has those multiple parameters required. Agreed that my objective function is not differentiable. Will try to provide a numerical example. Also, I want each element of `x` to be > 0. In that case, should I put this as a non-equality `constraints` or as a `bounds` parameter?

Comment: It's a simple bounds constraint, so I'd put it in as bounds on the variables. Note also that you can't use strict inequalities. However, you can model the strict inequality x > 0 by x >= ε, where ε is a sufficiently small positive number.